# Confusion regarding variables.title and more

Tags: session, coldfusion

Please consider two files (I am working inside Sessions). Inside my .cfm page, I am creating an instance of a component and setting some values like following:

**reports.cfm**

```
<cfset LineChartObj = createObject("component", "#LocalSessionDotPath#.lib.report.testchart").init() />
<cfset LineChartObj.setTitle("Type of Events") />
<cfset LineChartObj.setYAxisTitle("Event Rate") />
```

**testchart.cfc** (relevant functions)

```
<cffunction name="setTitle" returntype="void" output="false" access="public" hint="Set title for chart">
    <cfargument name="_Title" type="string" />
    <cfset variables.title = arguments._Title >
</cffunction

<cffunction name="setXAxisTitle" returntype="void" output="false" access="public" hint="Set xAxisTitle for chart">
    <cfargument name="_xAxisTitle" type="string" />
    <cfset variables.xAxisTitle = arguments._xAxisTitle >
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getXAxisTitle" returntype="string" access="public" hint="Get xAxisTitle of chart">
    <cfreturn variables.xAxisTitle>
</cffunction>
```

My questions are:

1. The function name defined as  "_Title" in `setTitle()` function can be anything, right? Not mandatory to take "_Title" ?
2. In `<cfset variables.title = arguments._Title >`, from where does the `variables.title` came from. Does it has something to do with session scope?

Comment: There is no reference to the `session` scope in the code above, so how does it relate to your question? RE: #1, the answer is yes (within limits), but .. you could answer that yourself by simply trying it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

1. Right. Whatever the name you use for the argument defines the name you need to use to refer to it in your function body.
2. The `variables` scope is the default 'private' scope of storing variables & functions in a CFC.  The code just explicitly declare to store `title` in the `variables` scope.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html